# Is there any similar way to replicate "qcut" function of pandas in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, statistics, data-science, kolmogorov-smirnov

I wanted to do the KS test in the pyspark for the predicted probability and true labels. The similar work has been done in the pandas in the link: https://www.listendata.com/2019/07/KS-Statistics-Python.html

Comment: check if this works - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#quantilediscretizer

Answer (score 0):

No there is no direct way. You have to apply window functions etc. I have always convert to pandas when I needed this :-) Or when I am working in a Databricks type environment I leverage spark sql. I have found these easier than the windowing methods.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot covert it to Pandas due to the data size. Can you write more about the window functions ? Thanks in advance :)